# Parsing Facebook Graph API results in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get some output parsing results from Facebook graph API (comments on a website)

Here is the script:

```
   if (document.getElementById('comments')) {

      var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+xid%2C+username%2C+text%2C+time+from+comment+where+object_id+in+%28select+comments_fbid+from+link_stat+where+url+%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fdroidsnip.blogspot.com%27%29";


      $.getJSON(url, function(data){

         var name = data.data;

     document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML = name[0].text;

         });

    }
```

and an html:

```
<p id="comments">Hello World</p>
```

And i canon get results from the script to be injected in html

Do I have mistakes in script? (I am not very good at js and jQuery)

I can't really debug this script to see until which line it executes (in case if I have it badly written)

Also here:
if I use dot notation in `data.data` then browser is not complaining, but if i use `data["data"]`, then i get mistake in this line, saying i must use dot notation

Comment: try adding `callback=?` to the end of your url: `var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+xid%2C+username%2C+text%2C+time+from+comment+where+object_id+in+%28select+comments_fbid+from+link_stat+where+url+%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fdroidsnip.blogspot.com%27%29&callback=?";
`

Comment: @AndreasAL still nothing happens, what does callback do? isn't it supposed to be used for forms if the page is referred back to itself?

Comment: because when i use data["data"] i get warning saying I should be using dot notation. For debugging i use http://jsbin.com/#source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/9wcvH/1/

Make sure you wrapped the code in document.ready statement:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 if (document.getElementById('comments')) {

      var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=select+xid%2C+username%2C+text%2C+time+from+comment+where+object_id+in+%28select+comments_fbid+from+link_stat+where+url+%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fdroidsnip.blogspot.com%27%29";

      $.getJSON(url, function(data){
         var name = data.data;
         document.getElementById('comments').innerHTML = name[0].text;
         });
    }
});
```